# Vertex Order/Initial Vertex in LineString

Tags: qgis, vertices

I would like to change the initial vertex in a LineString, I would also like to change the direction it is "drawn". Are methods available to edit this information?

The line is closed.

[image: vertex editor]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the line address
You can use the process, in the `process toolbox`, `Reverse line direction` tool (under options `Vector geometry tool`).

To change only the lines you are interested in, check the option `selected objects only.`

Comment: That solves the direction issue thank you, also provides a work around to change the initial vertex. I can "Split Features" on the vertex I want to be first, then "Reverse Line Direction" on the line containing the current first. Finally "Merge Vector Layers" and "Merge Selected Features" to put the feature back together...